# CMake + MSVC not generating *.vcxproj properly?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cmake

I am porting a lib called `pointmatcher` to windows, which is compiled well in linux with gcc.

My toolset in windows is CMake (3.18 / 3.20) with Visual Studio 16 2019 generator.

I am building shared libs so I tried to add `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)` to CMakeLists.txt. The *.dll, *.lib and *.exp are NOT generated after using `msbuild`.

And I encounted errors like this:

```bash
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.t
argets(31,5): error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\project\build\modules\pointmatcher\, \\pointmatcher.dll)" cannot be evaluated 
. The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share. [C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\project\build\mod 
ules\pointmatcher\pointmatcher.vcxproj]
```

Although I have set the `CMAKE_*_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` before this target as others did, I found that in the generated pointmatcher.vcxproj the `${OutDir}` is still not set correctly:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.20506.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">\\</OutDir>
    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">pointmatcher.dir\Debug\</IntDir>
    <TargetName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">pointmatcherd</TargetName>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">.dll</TargetExt>
    <LinkIncremental Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">true</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">\\</OutDir>
    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">pointmatcher.dir\Release\</IntDir>
    <TargetName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">pointmatcher</TargetName>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">.dll</TargetExt>
    <LinkIncremental Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">false</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|x64'">\\</OutDir>
    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|x64'">pointmatcher.dir\MinSizeRel\</IntDir>
    <TargetName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|x64'">pointmatcher</TargetName>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|x64'">.dll</TargetExt>
    <LinkIncremental Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|x64'">false</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|x64'">true</GenerateManifest>
    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|x64'">\\</OutDir>
    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|x64'">pointmatcher.dir\RelWithDebInfo\</IntDir>
    <TargetName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|x64'">pointmatcher</TargetName>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|x64'">.dll</TargetExt>
    <LinkIncremental Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|x64'">true</LinkIncremental>
    <GenerateManifest Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|x64'">true</GenerateManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
...
    </PreLinkEvent>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\boost_thread-vc140-mt.lib;C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\boost_filesystem-vc140-mt.lib;C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\boost_system-vc140-mt.lib;C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\boost_program_options-vc140-mt.lib;C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\boost_date_time-vc140-mt.lib;C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\boost_chrono-vc140-mt.lib;C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\boost_atomic-vc140-mt.lib;C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\yaml-cpp.lib;\\nabo.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions) /machine:x64</AdditionalOptions>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>false</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>%(IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries)</IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>
      <ImportLibrary>//pointmatcher.lib</ImportLibrary>
      <ModuleDefinitionFile>C:/Users/ContainerAdministrator/project/build/modules/pointmatcher/pointmatcher.dir/Release/exports.def</ModuleDefinitionFile>
      <ProgramDataBaseFile>//pointmatcher.pdb</ProgramDataBaseFile>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
    </Link>
```

Does that path `<ImportLibrary>//pointmatcher.lib</ImportLibrary>` cause the error?

Since I got another lib using __declspec(dllexport), which can be compiled successfully with the full path of `ImportLibrary` in its *.vcxproj.

How can I correctly configure?

Comment: It seems that the true problem is coming from the add_library(). Maybe cmake not generates the target(pointmatcher.dll) path correctly, so when we export this target or link to this target the `msbuild` said that path is invalid.